# Symfony2 Access Controls regex not working

Tags: symfony

I'm using following Acess Control in security.yml:

```
- { path: ^/g/+/submit, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

the "+" should make any word match, but it does not work if I try any of the urls like:

```
/g/something/submit
/g/somethingelse/submit
```

Are regular expressions not fully working in access controls in symfony2? Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was that I forgot to put a dot before the +. so a correct regex would be:

```
- { path: ^/g/.+/submit, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```